# How to manage permissions for .mdf file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, installation

I have a Windows application in C# that completely runs offline. I have used SQL Server as backend and use `.mdf`, `.ldf` files in my application for database access.

While creating setup file we have added these files in setup file.

Now the problem is when  we install setup file in client computer it creates a folder in

```
C:/'Default Company Name'
```

but every time we have to give permissions to these files through windows security option. Is there any way we can assign permissions once for all?

I hope I have made myself clear.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which tool you use to create the setup?

Comment: You can't just dump a `.mdf` file into a directory and then use it. You need to have **at least** SQL Server **Express** installed on that machine

Comment: i have used setup and deployment option of Visual studio

Comment: Yes i have installed SQL Server Express in clien't machine. Problem is application don't connect to database unitil i give full permissions for .mdf file